# How do I Get and Set geolocation to google maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

**The goal:**

I want a create a simple website that shows your levitation based on your adress (found through your IP) or the entered geocode.

**Where I'm stuck:**

I'm using http://ipinfo.io/ to track the users geolocation through the IP. 
It returns the geolocation as the response.loc (shown in the code below).

I then want to add that geolocation to google maps and have is as the default value.

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(59.6162,16.5528);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeLatLng() {
  var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
  var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
  var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
  var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
        map.setZoom(15);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map

        });
        infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

// get geocode from IP //

$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("Your IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html("Location: " + response.loc);
}, "jsonp");
```

```css
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #panel {
        position: relative;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        width: 350px;
      }
      #latlng {
        width: 225px;
      }
       #map-canvas {
        height: 50%;
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: 25%;
        margin-top: 5%;
       }

.cont {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  z-index:-10;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

h3 {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Find out your elevation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
  
  <div class="cont">

  <div><h3>Find out what your elevation is!</h3></div>
  <hr>
<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="address"></div>
<hr/>Geo location: <pre id="details"></pre>



    
    </div>
    <p align="center">Try a different geolocation:</p>
    <div id="panel">
      <input id="latlng" type="text" value="59.3323050,18.0528360">
      <input type="button" value="use geocode" onclick="codeLatLng()">
    </div>
    
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use http://ipinfo.io, but I find this [google geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) function, to find the position of the user according to the latitude and the longitude, then, just pass the position to your maps!

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
       if(navigator.geolocation) {
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
           var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude); // get the position based on the latitude and the longitude

           var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               map: map,
               position: pos, // set the position of the google map
               content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
           });

           map.setCenter(pos);
       }, function() {
          handleNoGeolocation(true);
       });
     } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }
}
```